# TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a form app and I don t understand the error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Code here;

```
class Myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid1()

class Grid1(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Grid1,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=1

        self.inside=GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols=2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Your name is :"))
        self.name=TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)


        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Your Last name is :"))
        self.lastname=TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastname)


        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Your email is :"))
        self.email=TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.submit=Button(text="Submit",font=40)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

if __name__=="__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

#### Error

```
File ".\kivyprima.py", line 38, in <module> Myapp().run()
File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run root = self.build()
File ".\kivyprima.py", line 10, in build return Grid1()
File ".\kivyprima.py", line 34, in init self.submit=Button(text="Submit",font=40)
File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 121, in init
```

Comment: `return Grid1()` here keyword arguments should be passed?

Comment: @OlvinRoght No, `**kwargs` is totally optional

Comment: @AlexOnel provide the full stacktrace

Comment: @DeepSpace, yes, I forgot to put question mark at the end of question.

Comment: File ".\kivyprima.py", line 38, in <module>
     Myapp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File ".\kivyprima.py", line 10, in build
     return Grid1()
   File ".\kivyprima.py", line 34, in __init__
     self.submit=Button(text="Submit",font=40)
   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 121, in __init__

Comment: super(ButtonBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 318, in __init__
     super(Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
     super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize))

Comment: Add the full traceback to the question; it's virtually unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Please update the title, it is misleading.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, so the error is actually **not** in your `super(Grid1,self).__init__(**kwargs)` statement, it's in the creation of the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button. You did:

```
self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font=40)
self.add_widget(self.submit)
```

But as the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) say, the font size is set by **`font_size`** and not **`font`**.  The code should be:

```
self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
self.add_widget(self.submit)
```

This should work just fine.

#### Edit

Just want to thank @chepner for pointing this out:

> Note that the issue, then, is that font, not being recognized by
> Button (or anyone else), is simply passed on up the chain until it is
> ultimately passed to `object.__init__` (which raises an error instead
> of simply ignoring unexpected arguments).

Comment: Note that the issue, then, is that `font`, not being recognized by `Button` (or anyone else), is simply passed on up the chain until it is ultimately passed to `object.__init__` (which raises an error instead of simply ignoring unexpected arguments).