# Python inheriting generic type: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, super

I am trying to make a class `Sprite` that inherits generic class `T`, with the bound of being a subclass of class `Object`. Class `Text` is a subclass of class `Object`. This is class `Text`, provided by outer library:

```py
# text.py
class Text(Object):
    # ignored properties...
    def __init__(self, text="placeholder text", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(object_type=Text.object_type, text=text, **kwargs)
```

This is my self-written class `Sprite`:

```py
# sprite.py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Object)

class Sprite(Generic[T]):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Sprite, self).__init__(self, clickable=True, evt_handler=self.click_wrapper, **kwargs)
```

And such a `Sprite` instance is initialized by:

```py
  sprite = Sprite[Text](
    text="This is a sprite!",
    object_id="spriteTest",
    # other similar arguments...
  )
```

And this is the error thrown:

```
Exception thrown in main()! Terminating main...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sprite.py", line 79, in main
    sprite = Sprite[Text](
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 687, in __call__
    result = self.__origin__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "sprite.py", line 47, in __init__
    super(Sprite, self).__init__(self, clickable=True, evt_handler=self.click_wrapper, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: object.\_\_init\_\_() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672872/typeerror-object-init-takes-exactly-one-argument-the-instance-to-initial)

Comment: @dsillman2000 No, the error messages are the same but the answer turns out to be a library-specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding Generic Type variables here. Let me first try to reduce your bug down to its most minimal variant:

```py
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

Sprite(text="My text")
```

This very simple program throws the exact same Exception as you have:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../72690805.py", line 57, in <module>
    Sprite(text="My text")
  File ".../72690805.py", line 55, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The key here is that it is `object` for who you cannot specify anything other than one argument. With other words, the superclass of `Sprite` is `object` in both of our cases (i.e. the default Python object, not your `Object` class). Your `Sprite` class simply does not have a non-default superclass.

You seem to be of the understanding that your `super(...).__init__(...)` call will initialize `Text` whenever you use `Sprite[Text](...)`, but that is not the case. Let me give a common example of a Generic type variable in use:

```py
from typing import List, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Queue(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.queue: List[T] = []

    def put(self, task: T) -> None:
        self.queue.append(task)

    def get(self) -> T:
        return self.queue.pop(-1)

queue = Queue()
queue.put(12)
queue.put(24)
queue.put(36)
# queue.put('a') # <- A type checker should disallow this
print(queue.get())
print(queue.get())
print(queue.get())
```

Here, we have a simple Queue class, with `put` and `get` methods. These functions are supplemented with Type hints via T, and now type checkers know that e.g. `Queue[int]().get` returns an `int`.
However, the `super().__init__()` is still just the standard initialization of the Python `object`. We're not suddenly initializing an `int`, which is equivalent to what you seem to be trying.

To wrap up; whenever you find yourself using functionality from the `typing` module to try and get something working, then you're making a mistake. As far as I'm aware, all the functionality from `typing` is merely "cosmetic", and is ignored by Python. It exists to allow developers to use type checkers to ensure that they are not making mistakes, e.g. calling `queue.put('a')` when `queue` was initialized with `Queue[int]()`. To reiterate, this `put` of a character will still execute in Python, and it will place the character in the queue, even though a Type checker would tell you that it's wrong.

Comment: Oh! I made the mistake thinking that `Sprite(Generic[T])` is *inheriting* `T`. I will try writing `Sprite` as a wrapper of `T` containing one `T`-typed variable. I still have another question though: what does the `super().__init__()` in your example do? What is the `super()` for `Queue[T]` in this case?

Comment: I believe that the `super().__init__()` is not necessary here, as my understanding is that calling `__init__()` on an `object` is moot. However, my VSCode Python extension autocompletes `def __ini` into `def __init__(self) -> None:`, either followed by `pass` if the class has no superclass, and `super().__init__()` if it does have a superclass. The extension is not smart enough to recognize that the initialization is likely not needed with `Generic` as a superclass.